# Clone brush not working for me in blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am using the new Blender 2.8 and was doing a tutorial on making a seamless texture using the clone brush. The tutorial I was watching I think was done in Blender 2.79 But the Control and LMB just don't seem to do anything. I am sure I am missing something but not sure what. I read some of the other comments about the clone brush not working but they were for older versions of Blender. [image]

Comment: What keymap are you using right now? Are you on LMB select, and could it be possible that you might need to use LMB +control click to assign the cursor location for clone?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I never changed the preferences and left select like it should be or at least what I am used to. But in either case it does not work no matter what I click first. Nothing happens at all. The little cross hair does not appear not has it ever appeared ha. Very frustrating as there are not many videos on the clone painting brush. At least not with the new Blender.

Comment: Where are you painting, in the 3d view or in the Image Editor? Controls are different in each. Ctrl-click to place cursor in 3d view, and paint to copy the area under the cursor. In the Image Editor, the Clone brush has to use a second image selected to appear over the original image as in a full-size stencil that you move with the rmb and paint into. This is the original design of the Clone tool that should have been changed to a different tool altogether and allow the Clone tool behavior from the 3d view in the 2d view.

Comment: I tried painting in both but what I discovered after doing more research online is that I had my plane upside down. I could paint on the reverse side of the plane and also see the cross hairs but could not move them. Now I did not know this could be an issue. I still could not get the Ctrl-click to work but I could paint in the 3D view. After reading your comment on this I will have to revisit this process. I was able to paint out the seams enough to make my texture repeat without seeing any seams.  I will have to go through that tutorial again for a third time as I must me missing something.

Comment: That means you found your answer - you had needed to invert your face normal. It does happen sometimes with image planes.

Comment: I do appreciate the help as it makes me go back and scratch my head some more. I read the manual on the clone brush but it was a very short read. But I still can't move the cross hairs with Control LMB. But am glad I can use the clone tool but it would be nice to sample different areas of the texture. I wonder how a person tells one side of the plane from another?

Comment: In edit mode you can turn on the face normals in the view overlays and see which direction they are going - this is a very common thing, so if you have any other painting problem on a model, this is the first thing to check. If you want better control of placing copies of pixels, load up a copy of the image as a brush texture set to Stencil, and then you can move it around and scale it up/down, rotate it to align it to your target with much mode control than the clone tool.

Comment: Craig thanks for the tips. I will give this a try.